# convert time to total hours and calculate from mysql data with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html field:

```
<label for="Time-2">Time :</label>
<input type="number" name="Time-2">
```

and the DB is as follows:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| id | Time-1 | Time-2 | Percentage |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| 1  |  300   |   10   |            |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
```

Here the Time-1 and Time-2 are in minutes

Time-2 from DB will be input from the html, Time -1 values are filled from other html field. When input is given am looking for a php code where in the time(Time -2) has to be converted from hours and minutes to total minutes 
and calculate the formula ((Time-1 - Time-2) / Time-1) * 100. and the result is to be inserted in Percentage column of the same row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Share more info about what you have tried so far, someone will probably flag this otherwise.

Comment: Show us what you have attempted to do do far! Otherwise this looks like a specification for some code you want written for free.SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service**

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to update the table in the database to set the percentage column

```
UPDATE time_table set percentage = (time1 - time2)*100/time1 WHERE time1 <> 0;
```

This will update every row in the table so that the percentage is shown. But that begs the question. Do do you really need to save the percentage in the table? The answer is no!!

You can just as easily calculate it at the time of retrieval

```
SELECT id, time1, time2 , (time1 - time2)*100/time1 as percentage from time_table
```

So you can actually drop the percentage column!

Finally get onto user input if the time is given as HH:MM the easiest thing to do is to split

$parts = split($input,":");
   $time2 = $parts[0] * 60 + $parts[1]

Comment: Thank you for that...Can you please tell me how can i convert the input time to total minutes ?..which i can use for calculation..

Comment: Depends on what you consider time 0 to be.

Comment: Time format will be HH:MM separated by ':' .which has to be converted into minutes.

Comment: Updated the answer